# Balances are different

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

In Geth, if I check my balance, it says one number.
At etherchain.org it says another number which is higher and more accurate and includes my transaction history.
I wanted to convert my balance to bitcoin so I signed up on kraken. 
It gave me an address to send it to in order to 'deposit' it for me presumably into my kraken account.
It seems I then trade it for btc.
It looks like, in order to send my balance to kraken, I have to use geth, but if geth has the wrong and lower balance, how do I access and send the rest to kraken?

I know my wallet number (the 0x*****) thing and I know the password for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

One more quick note, the last few transactions I received happened while geth was not syncing properly.  I had to update it for it to sync right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had to update it for it to sync right.

Yes, you balance on geth node is different from etherscan is because your chain is not is sync. You can use command `eth.syncing` to know how total blocks and the no of blocks you have downloaded.

> how do I access and send the rest to kraken?

One way is to wait for the node be in sync and then you can transfer the balance to your Kraken account.

Else you could use thrid-parties like [My Ether Wallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction). Simply unlock your account with any of the possible methods (I think you have keystore and password, so go with that), and send ethers to your kraken account.

Comment: it seems geth is not synchronizing.  it imports a few chain segments then says 'deduplicating database entries' then repeats but with new chain segments   --fast does not seem to help   been like this abd not synched for over 2 days